# Div flickers on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

I have read a lot of the questions on here but can't find one that fixes this. I have programmed a div to follow my cursor. I only want it to appear when the cursor is over #backgroundiv. I have got it working but it sometimes randomly flickers on chrome and disappears entirely on firefox. Even more randomly is it sometimes appears to work and then starts flickering. I have tried a variety of things from hover to mouseenter/mouseover but nothing seems to work.

What I want is for #newdot to appear when the cursor is over #backgroundiv and then follow the cursor around the div. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
//hide dot when leaves the page
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#backgroundiv").hover(function() {
    $("#newdot").removeClass("hide");
  }, function() {
    $("#newdot").addClass("hide");
  });
});

//div follows the cursor
$("#backgroundiv").on('mousemove', function(e) {
  //below centres the div
  var newdotwidth = $("#newdot").width() / 2;
  $('#newdot').css({
    left: e.pageX - newdotwidth,
    top: e.pageY - newdotwidth
  });
});
//tried below too but it doesn't work
/*$(document).ready(function(){
           $("#backgroundiv").mouseenter(function(){
           $("#newdot").removeClass("hide");
           });
           $("#backgroundiv").mouseout(function(){
           $("#newdot").addClass("hide");
           });
        }); */
```

```css
#backgroundiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

#newdot {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="newdot"></div>
<div id="backgroundiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not issue but a logical behavior, when you hover on the blue div you trigger `mouseenter` so you remove the class and you see the red one BUT when you hover the red one you trigger `mouseleave` from the blue div thus you add the class and you hide the red one. Now the red is hidden you trigger again the `mouseenter` on the blue div and you remove the class again and the red div is shown, and so on ... this is the flicker.

To avoid this you can consider the hover on the red box to make the red box appear on its hover when you lose the hover from the blue one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#backgroundiv").hover(function() {
    $("#newdot").removeClass("hide");
  }, function() {
    $("#newdot").addClass("hide");
  });
});
//div follows the cursor
$("#backgroundiv").on('mousemove', function(e) {
  //below centres the div
  var newdotwidth = $("#newdot").width() / 2;
  $('#newdot').css({
    left: e.pageX - newdotwidth,
    top: e.pageY - newdotwidth
  });
});
```

```css
#backgroundiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

#newdot {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}


/* Added this code */

#newdot:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newdot">
</div>
<div id="backgroundiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. To help me understand, what is the importance of adding display:block? What does it do?

Comment: display:block is the opposite of display:none in your case so i simply said `on hover show the div don't keep it hide` ... it can also be display:inline-block, the idea is to override the display:none

Comment: That works but it no longer hides when it leaves the side. I think it's because it's hovering over the red square. Can it be tweaked so it hides when it leaves the backroundiv?

Comment: @bevan7 in the snippet it hides for me, not you ?